# how to patch all deployments at a time

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am  running below command to restart pods , but i could able to patch one deployment at a time, requirement is to patch all the deployments in namespace at a time.

```
  oc patch deploy  buy-api  -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

Could somebody help me to find command to apply patch for all the deployments in one shot.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The [API](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#patch-deployment-v1-apps) itself doesn't support modifying more than one deployment. So you would need something to loop over the deployments.

Comment: yea, need help on  how can i make it to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk and xargs you can do that:

```
oc get deploy | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs oc patch deploy $0  -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

Comment: `oc`/`kubectl` can output just the name: `oc get deploy -o name`